# How to increment with limited value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hello everyone i am Working on table in with i have around 2million records and i want to add two column PageNo and serialNo based on acc_no

Eg:-

```
acc_no PageNo SerialNo
abc1   0001   0001
cbf2   0001   0002
.
.
zcd6   0001   9999
```

Once SerialNo Reach to 9999 then PageNo Start With 0002

```
eg:- 
acc_no PageNo SerialNo
abc1   0002   0001
cbf2   0002   0002
.
.
zcd6   0002   9999
```

and So on
 I have tried

```
Select right('0000'+cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by acc_no) as varchar(100)),4) PageNo,acc_no from [table Name]
```

But i am not getting how to do Need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
select acc_no, ((rno-1) /9999) +1 pageNo,  ((rno-1) % 9999) + 1 SerialNo
from (
    SELECT acc_no , (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by acc_no )) rno
    FROM [table Name]
) t
```

Comment: thanks for answer but when PageNo start with 2 SerialNo start with 0 i want it start with 1

Comment: Its Working Thanks a Lot @Milad

Answer (score 2):

You may try with this:

```
SELECT 
    Acc_No, 
    ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Acc_No) - 1) / 9999 + 1) AS PageNo,
    ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Acc_No) - 1) % 9999 + 1) AS SerialNo
FROM [Table Name]
```

Columns `PageNo` and `SerialNo` are returned as numbers, so you'll need to convert them as you expect e.g. `SELECT FORMAT(1, '0000') -- 0001`.